# View logging output from Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I've been trying to make an Azure function.

How can I tell if it's running?

I'm using an `ILogger` to output log messages, so I expect to see them.

I was kind of also expecting a log of invocations and results.

Do such things exist?

Comment: OK, I've found: Home -> function resource name -> functions -> function name -> Monitor that sounds promising, but it just shows a spinner.

Answer (score 12):

Except the monitor of the azure function, you can also use logs in kudu to view the output of your azure function app.

And compared with the monitor of the azure function, kudu log files is more timely.

Just go to this url: `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

And then go to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\yourtriggername>`, then you will find the log files. Monitor usually takes a certain time to display (usually 5 minutes), but the log file in kudu is real-time.

It is not recommended to use the ilogger module that comes with the azure function on the portal. It is very fragile and will not be displayed.

Comment: It only shows a spinner. Whatever this is it's completely broken.

Comment: `ILogger` is the normal way to log, what's the problem?

Comment: That `DebugConsole` thing does indeed have some logs. Is that really the only way to see any evidence of what a function app is doing? That's shit!

Comment: Really: how are you _supposed_ to check that a function app is working? Surely it can't be this difficult?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Under normal circumstances, everyone likes to use the Ilogger tab to determine whether the function is triggered. At the beginning, I also relied on the Ilogger tab, but then I found that this Ilogger tab was quite fragile. Many times it did not display anything, which led to my misjudgment of the function app. My advice is not to rely on the Ilogger tab, this thing is not reliable.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Application Insights and the monitor that comes with the function are both a good way, but there may be shortcomings that they are not absolutely instantaneous. If you want to know the status of the function fundamentally, directly entering the console is the ultimate method.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Any more doubts? If no more doubts, can we end this question now?:)

Comment: @CindyPau I am trying to view the output of print statements from my python code. Tried many many things but not able to do so. It is really bad. What needs to be done for this? Is there an article or something?

Answer (score 2):

I have found success in this by navigating to

<my function app> → Monitoring → Log Stream

and then running my function. This will show all the messages <my function app> produces going forward. It does not show past messages. That is the drawback. It isn't useful for going back after an event occurred to determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and worked with Azure support.  I am also looking for the standard output logs.  They said they might have a way to do this and would get back to me.

I found more error messages by going to the Function App, then Diagnose and Solve Problems -> Availability and Performance -> Python Function or Function Execution and Errors.  These areas contained more better info on errors.

For python, you can also import logging and use logging.info("Your message here") to provide debug messages to the log that you can view under Log Stream.